# C abstract-data-type program stuck when run it

Tags: c, generic-programming, abstract-data-type

As part of my studies, I have to prepare an ADT generic set in C.
When I run the program it does not come to an end.
I believe there is a problem in the destory function 
and in the 
when i comment free(s) in the destory func and mySet->freefunc in the pop func
the program work well.

I would appreciate if you can help me understand exactly what the problem is.

```
void destroy (Set s){
if (s == NULL)
    return;
while (s->top > 0 && pop(s) == Success) ;

if(s->array != NULL)
    free(s->array);
if(s != NULL)
  //  free(s);
return;}


Result pop(Set mySet){
if ((mySet == NULL) || (mySet->top == 0))
    return Fail ;

mySet->top--;
//mySet->freefunc(mySet->array[mySet->top]);
return Success ;}

void freefunc(Elem x){
if(x != NULL)
    free(x);}
```

`typedef void* Elem;
typedef set_t* Set;`

```
struct set_t{
Elem* array ;
int top ;
int maxCapacity ;
copy_fnc copfunc;
free_fnc freefunc;
compare_fnc compfunc;};
```

I also attached a link to github along with the program and files

https://github.com/gun0071/ADT_set

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd be better off with a minimal complete example and describing what you have done so far to debug you program. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please put the code in the question.  If it is too big to fit into the question, then please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Also, you should demonstrate how you know that the problem is in the 'destroy' function.

Comment: If the program doesn't terminate at all, it's still running - just attach a debugger and see where it is, and what it's doing.

Comment: When you program in Pico (the programming language, not the editor), it is OK to use Pico-style indentation.  Although the compiler doesn't care, people programming in C should use either Allman (my preferred style) or 1TBS — and not Pico style.  See Wikipedia on [Indent style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for including some code, but please note that what you've included is not an MCVE.  An MCVE is complete — meaning it can be compiled.  We've got to invent code to make this compile into a program, and we can't tell what you've done when you wrote the missing code.  (For example, is there a `typedef struct set_t Set;` or equivalent somewhere?)  And no, we shouldn't have to go to GitHub to find out what you've done.  Your question should be complete without depending crucially on any external site.